# Android webview scrolling issue

Tags: android, scroll, webview

How can i handle the scrolling in webview such that when cursor comes below certain line, cursor automatically scrolls above it. Is there any function because it can be handled by IOs but i am not finding anything for android.

Comment: Added sample code of webview. So that it'll be easy to help

Comment: @ Vinayaga:- I have imported this library :- https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/ . In this as soon as if cursor is below keyboard it shifts above it but now i am adding some horizontal line say of height 10 dp above keyboard . But cursor is hiding behind that bar . How can i handle it

Answer (score 1):

I happy I can help you with this issue!

The solution is really simple! I'm using the same rich editor.

I was facing the same problem and I solve it removing the **ScrollView**.

What you have to do is on your layout create a Linear layout and inside it put the editor. Just one thing you should include as tag in Linear layout:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

This is my layout (**Note: I changed the name of the control**)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
            android:background="@drawable/background_container_corner_white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <com.glaucioleonardo.wcmauditor.activities.editor.RichEditor
                android:id="@+id/editor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need to use those tags in Linear layout. I just use them to format according to my app

```
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_container_corner_white"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Now it's working perfectly! If you don't solve your problem, please post your layout and will be easier to help you!